# Appending to an array in a loop - Python

Tags: python, vectorization

**Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54983763/appending-values-to-an-array-within-an-object-looping-over-objects) question for streamlined version with no clutter**

I am writing a gravity simulation. The structure of my code is:

- A `solution` array - this contains the (already computed) solution for the system of masses. Because of the nature of solving differential equations in Python, all the relevant values (each component of position and velocity for every mass at every time value) are in a the `solution` array.
- An array `masses`. The objects here contain all the information about every mass including the arrays `x_history`which I am trying to update below.
- No. of dimensions `d`. Here I have used 2 for simplicity.

I have the following code:

```
d = 2
for i in range(len(masses)): #  loop through masses
    for k in range(len(solution)): # loop through solution to obtain values at each timestep
        x = []  #  d dimensional x vector at current timestep
        #  fill the x-vector
        for j in range(d):
            x.append(solution[k][d * i + j])
        masses[i].x_history.append(x)
```

The idea is simply to loop through the objects in the `masses` array, abstract the relevant information from another array (`x` arrays representing vectors), and add it to the `x_history` arrays in the mass objects.
The problem is (I have checked this by debugging) in the lines:

```
masses[i].x_history.append(x)
```

Rather than appending to `masses[i].x_history` for the current value of `i`, the code appends it to the `x_history` array for all the objects in the masses list, meaning that at the end of the outer loop every object in the masses list contains **all** the information rather than only its own.

Does anyone have any idea as to why this might be the case? Am I accidentally vectorizing this operation or something?

Comment: Why not just append them directly to `self.masses[i].(x/v)_history`? Or use [`extend`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_extend.htm)

Comment: Sorry, could you expand? I do not know what you mean by 'directly'. I have done a fair amount of programming in other languages but not Python

Comment: As in `self.masses[i].x_history.append(solution[k]...` instead of `x.append(solution[k]...`.

Comment: Can you please try to [remove the clutter from the code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to let others reproduce the actual problem you have?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog because I am making smaller arrays from the larger arrays solution array, and then adding them

Comment: @moooeeeep will do

Comment: Does not (self.masses[i].x_history).append(x) and work (self.masses[i].v_history).append(v) work?

Comment: @zabop unfortunately not

Answer (score 0):

Seems you made the loop correct but appending the value to self.masses[i].x_history at wrong indented position. You have to move that last two line statements one intended (four space) back.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is in the right place - I am appending many arrays within x_array

Comment: You probably wanted to write intend -> indent.

Comment: I agree with you. seems the last two appends should be outdented to loop only a the first for.

Comment: @VPfB ThankU :-)